# Test Mobile Connect SMS Send from SFMC Without Short/ Long Code

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I have got SFMC with No Long Code provisioned in it. I want to test SMS send from Salesforce to Marketing Cloud. I want to do this via API call Salesforce To SFMC.

I have tried creating Message template in SFMC, but there it asks for Short/long code. I am not able to create any message.

To send SMS from Marketing Cloud, it must to have a long code. or is there a way to test without it with the help of API calls.

Answer (score 4):

You will need a short/long code before you can use MobileConnect.

When an account is initially provisioned, it doesn't include a short/long code, even if this is included in your licence. This has to go through a separate process as the short/long code assignment process varies by country (as different countries use different aggregators).

To initiate the short/long code provisioning you will need to reach out to your SFMC Account Executive, as they will need to start the process of the long code acquisition on your behalf (you can raise a support ticket, but they will tell you exactly the same thing).

The SFMC Provisioning team can then setup the code until once receive they receive the short/long code details.

Comment: Thanks Eliot!  Appreciate your response. Can it be possible that a dummy number is provisioned as Long Code and then a message can be created and Activated on SFMC.  I just want to test to reach to this message in SMFC VIA API Call and get a response. Thanks

Comment: No you can't have a 'dummy number' provisioned.